# Is it possible to run one project after building another?

Tags: dotnet-sdk

I want to patch dependency assemblies of my project. In solution I created PatcherProject and MainProject. Is it possible run PatcherProject after MainProject build process finished?

Comment: You can't directly define the build order. You can define dependencies between projects and MSBuild will determine the build order of projects based on the dependencies.

Comment: For MSBuild, a project is something that is built. Is it not an operation or tool. If you have a common build step, don't make a special project for it. Define a target and re-use the target across projects. The target can be in its own file that is imported or it can be in a file named 'Directory.Build.targets' which is automatically imported.